# Date validation is not working for some condition

Tags: javascript, asp.net, date, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I want to validate date in such a way so that it should take only 3 month back date from yesterday
i.e. DATE should be >= 3 months and < Current date.

I am getting output as wanted but after alert message its setting that day what ever the user selected. Even-though i have mention `return false;` and added `" UserDate = new Date();"`  its not setting "UserDate" to current date. Why its not working. Please help me. Any one can help me in that
Thanks in Advance

CODE:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtdate" AutoComplete="off" placeholder="Enter Sales Date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="TDate"
runat="server" TargetControlID="txtdate" Format="dd-MMM-yyyy"></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function TDate() {
        var UserDate = document.getElementById("txtdate").value;
        var ToDate = new Date();
        var minDate = new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 3);
        if (new Date(UserDate) > ToDate || new Date(UserDate) < new Date(minDate)) {
             alert('Selection date should be within 3 month from yesturday');
                 return false;
                    }
              return true;
                }
       </script>
```

[After clicking "OK" its again selected 29th date which i don't want i want to select select Yesterday date by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG0s9.png)

Comment: just a note: january = 0

Comment: @DavorMlinaric I am not getting what you want to say ? Please explain

Answer (score 0):

This Enable only 3 months from current date in bootstrap datepicker.

```
var lastDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()+3, today.getDate());


$("#startdate").datepicker({
  isDisabled: function(date) {
    return date.valueOf() < Date.now() ? false : true;
  },
  startDate: "dateToday", // If you need to disable past dates
  autoClose: true,
  viewStart: 0,
  weekStart: 1,
  endDate: lastDate,
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy"
});
```

Comment: Because i am using ajax Toolkit instead of date picker

Comment: Selection of date should be less then Current date